# GeoIP information in stackdriver logs for backend bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For *google_compute_backend_service* I can provide *custom_request_headers* to get GeoIP information in HTTP Headers.

Is it somehow possible to achieve similar thing with *google_compute_backend_bucket*, and see GeoIP information in stackdriver logging mechanism?

After some research I don't think it's possible, but maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are managing your project using Terraform

From [google_compute_backend_bucket](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_backend_bucket.html) article the argument/attribute custom_request_headers is not available, I noticed it is only in beta for [google_compute_backend_service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_backend_service.html) so you might want to provide feedback ti [HashiCorp](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform) (owners of Terraform) to support it